# setInterval to display div if ajax returns data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, setinterval

I'm trying to simulate a homemade push notification using `setInterval` but not sure how to do this. The ajax request works just fine at displaying messages. This is not the problem. I'm trying to display a separate notification in the `section style='notification'`.

**Ajax snippet**

```
  setInterval(function(){
 $.ajaxSetup({
     cache:false,
     type: "GET",
    url: "log.php",
    data: data,
 }); 
      $('#displayMessage').load('log.php');

     //display div notification if return data
     //document.getElementById('notification').style.display = 'block';  

}, 3000);
```

**markup**

```
   <section style='display:none;' id='notification' class="notif notif-notice alert  alert-dismissable">
      <h6 class="notif-title">Congratulations!
      <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
      </h6>
      <p>You have just received a new message</p>
    </section>
```

Comment: Your `load` call is operating on the element with id `displayMessage`.  But there's no element with that id in your markup.  What are you expecting this to do?

Comment: @RJM: trying to display section notification

Comment: @RJM: to get things clear I updated my question. The problem has nothing to do with displayMessage. It works great. I`m just trying to display a separate stand alone div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript's .load() method has an optional argument that is a function to do after the load is completed. It would look like this:

```
$('#displayMessage').load('log.php', function(){
    $('#notification').show();
});
```

Comment: Note that the callback function will be invoked regardless of success or error condition. You do not have an indication here of whether data was returned, or if an error occurred.

Comment: That's true. I didn't account for that because dealing with the exception of the thing not loading seemed like a separate question to me. I think the more effective method might be to put a .load() method in the `log.php` file which would reveal the div, but I don't know what's in that file or if the questioner has any control of it, so I didn't suggest that.

Comment: @jimboweb: in the log.php there is a while statement yes.